# Heroku containerized app won't run - error code H10

Tags: reactjs, docker, heroku, deployment

I'm new to Docker and trying to deploy my first containerized app on Heroku.  I created a react app using 'create-react-app', built an image, and can run it locally (basic instructions are at [https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/]).
I created a new app on Heroku, deploying the code via my GitHub repo.  I pushed the image to heroku registry and released it to the app. My first effort failed with an H14 error, so I made sure my dyno was scaled up using 'heroku ps:scale web=1'.  I also add the following to the Dockerfile, per the Heroku docs:

```
RUN adduser -D myuser
USER myuser
```

I re-built the image, pushed and released it again, and after opening the app got an H10 error, which is non-specific.

The logs show '> react-scripts start', and 'Starting the development server...', but right after that, they say 'heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0'.  Heroku goes through this process twice, and then spits out:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=containerized-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=0794c509-8e9d-4bc5-9217-f1a254a5c357 fwd="97.116.93.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I'm not finding any information to help with this.  Other, non-containerized, apps on Heroku are running, so the problem must be with this one specifically.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
#pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

#set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add '/app/node_modules/.bin' to $Path
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.0 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# set up non-root user (recommended for Heroku)
RUN adduser -D myuser
USER myuser

# start App
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

EDIT:  I built the image again and pushed it to Heroku, but I am now not able to release the image to the app.  I get "Expected response to be successful, got 404". I am not finding any help with this error.

Suggestions?

Comment: How do you set the port of your application? I would share the Dockerfile. When deploying on Heroku you need to bind to the port provided by the platform ($PORT env variable)

Comment: My Dockerfile:#pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

#set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add '/app/node_modules/.bin' to $Path
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.0 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# set up non-root user (recommended for Heroku)
RUN adduser -D myuser
USER myuser

# start App
CMD ["npm", "start"]

Comment: I've seen reference to binding a port, but the example I followed didn't do that.  I've also seen a Dockerfile for a Python app that binds a port, but I don't know how to do that in a Nodejs Dockerfile.  I added the Dockerfile to the original post.

Comment: I think you application must bind to the port number specified in the PORT environment variable. A good reference is https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error

Comment: The app has no server.js or similar file that connects (or 'listens') to any port.  That information is provided via the Dockerfile.  However, Heroku does not support the EXPOSE command, so how is port binding done?  The python app example in Heroku docs uses "CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT wsgi".  Is there an equivalent for Node?